# Angular 4 (Click) binding not working with Datatable Server Side

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

My problem is when I need to "render" a datatable column with custom HTML the angular binding seems to be lost.

Basically Datatable gives a (`render`) Callback so you can inject HTML in the column.

For my case one of my columns is a dropdown with Actions button.

**Here is my Datatable options:**

Take a closer look at the 4th column

```
this.dtOptions = {
  searching: false,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  columns: [
    { data: "Class" },
    { data: "Locked" },
    { data: "IterationNumber" },
    {
      data: "FileID",
      render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
        return `<div class="ui compact menu">
              <div  class="actions ui pointing dropdown link item">
                  Actions...
                  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class="menu">
                      <a class="item" (click)="finalizeDocument()">Finalize</a>
                      <a class="item" (click)="addIterationOfDocument()">Add Iteration</a>
                      <a class="item">Delete</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>`;
      }
    }
  ],
  ajax: {
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "api/document/search",
    method: "POST",
    data: (d: any) => {
      d.filter = this.filter;
      return JSON.stringify(d);
    }
  }
};
```

The semantic dropdown is rendered but the angular `(click)` binding is not working.

I've tried to use an Angular Dynamic Component with no success.

Is there a way to reapply the angular binding?

**Note: the same HTML place directly in the component is working.**

Comment: You probably need to call [`DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), on the string returner by the renderer, somehow (sorry don't know anything about `dt`).

Comment: Datatable basically give me a callback to inject html in the column simple as that. So how exactly by using the bypassSecurity I will be able to apply the binding?

Comment: I _assume_ it currently does nothing because you're trying to use that library to inject raw HTML with brackets into your page, hoping it will create a binding. I suspect Angular treats this HTML as unsanitized and ignores its contents. It's just a theory, I don't use `dt`.